# delphi 7 closing available modal form Onactivate under certain condition

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

im working on a project using **delphi 7**, The project is a maintenance project and im not the original coder of the project, i have a situation where i need to close a **available** form after it had been created through **code** under certain situations,The form is model

here is sample code of that

```
       var 
       frmStratum : TfrmStratum;
       begin
          if not assigned(frmStratum) then myMainForm.OnExecute(PropAction);
        end;
```

inside  myMainForm.OnExecute(PropAction); i have

```
frmStratum := TfrmStratum.Create(Self, Self as IStratum,inttostr(m_surveyno),Module,m_stations,false);
```

now the **procedure TfrmStratum.FormActivate** of **TfrmStratum**   i do lots of calucaltion and write to database

```
var
  if (bMassStratumExport) AND (bDoneOne)  then
  begin
             //write to database..
  end;
```

now i have to do this atleast **20 times** 
  that is

```
1. Create the form
2. onactivate do database writing
3. close TfrmStratum
```

since it is a modal form i cannot close if below from where i create it,so i wanted to close it onactivate as soon as the **step 2** is done

now i have tried this

```
  if (bMassStratumExport) AND (bDoneOne) AND NOT (bReadyToclose) then
 begin
    //do database writing
    if bNowClo then frmStratum.close;
 end
```

**EDIT :**(edited to make the question more clear)

Onactivate of the form(frmStratum) , i want to close the modal form (frmStratum),so i do this

```
procedure TfrmStratum.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if (bMassStratumExport) AND (bDoneOne) AND NOT (bReadyToclose) then
    begin
      //do database writing
      if bNowClo then self.close;// i need to close the form after after doing database write
    end
  end;
```

but the control while bugging goes to self.close but it doesnt close the form.
how to tackle this ?

Comment: Excuse me for being dense, but why are you creating a form, showing it and doing stuff in onactivate just to close it immediately when that is done? What is the purpose of having all this in a form then?

Comment: @MarjanVenema : lots of calucaltion is being done by the original code for the form on Oncreate of the form and without the calculation icannot do database write ,and the new requiement is i have to do the writing atleast 20 times,that is create the form..write to database and close the form..repeat 20 times atleast and i cannot make major changes to the code

Comment: If the calculation is performed in the `FormCreate` method, why bother attempting to `ShowModal` the form? The calculation is all done once the form is created, afterwards you only need to write the results. What am I missing? Even if some part of the calculation, or perhaps the writing itself, should take place in `FormActivate`, can you not just call the handler directly in `OnExecute`? Like this: `frmStratum.FormActivate(frmStratum);`. That isn't a really nice way of solving this, but I understand you've got particular difficulties re-factoring someone else's code properly at the moment.

Comment: Ok, I understand I think: (major refactor out of the question). Setting ModalResult is the normal way to close a form that is shown by ShowModal, but I am not sure that this would work from an OnActivate handler...

Comment: @MarjanVenema: I think it would, nice idea. There's also some chance that the OP expects the `Close` method to work immediately, like some sort of `Exit`.

Comment: @AndriyM major refactoring is very difficult at the moment.

Comment: @PresleyDias: I see, that's why I am not suggesting it. You could just call (or try calling) `FormActivate` extrinsically without showing the form, that way you wouldn't need to close it. That *might* require additional tuning, though, but might still be relatively easy to implement. Anyway, you seem to have found a solution that works for you, congrats!

Comment: @all, the Code is in such a way that i have to run through the Oncreate ..let it finish..then onactive let the database writing be done..then immediately close the form and repeat the procedure (for alot of times)..

Comment: @AndriyM : thanx for the idea..sure i will try it...seems which one do you think is cleaner calling >FormActivate or postmessage  ? in my case

Comment: @PresleyDias: I am definitely not satisfied with calling `FormActivate` explicitly. I would see that only as a temporary solution. So, of the two, Mark Elder's solution would be my choice. But did you try Marjan Venema's suggestion about setting `ModalResult` (to something like `mrOk` or `mrCancel`)? To me, that would be an even cleaner solution (if it worked).

Comment: Something like `if bNowClo then Self.ModalResult := mrOk;`

Comment: @AndriyM : ok, ...i tried **ModalResult** but it didnt work for me, it tried mrAbort also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the past when I needed to close a form during activation I posted a message to myself instead of calling self.close.

```
PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
```

I tried to find my original source that pointed me in this direction but I could not find it.

PostMessage will return immediately and not wait for the message to be processed.  Once the OnActivate function is finished and the message Delphi processing loop processes the message close will be called on your form.

Comment: hey PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);..the way i needed it to be..but y self.close doesnot work, but PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
 works?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming its  frmStatum, being invalid that's giving you the A/V exception

if bNowClo then self.close;

Comment: Or just `Close`, yes. The `frmStratum` in the `OnActivate` handler is likely an auto-generated variable, and the `frmStatus` in the method that creates the form is a local one, albeit with the same name.

Comment: It's that damn stupid local form variable. Put there for newbies, but guaranteed to get them in a mess in short order. I think it was identified as a bad idea in version 1....

Comment: They are need primarily for auto-created forms, I think. Either way, I agree, they must be very confusing to newbies.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson :thanks i tried that, AV are gone, but i have edited the question to what i actually wanted,..on Onactivate i need to close the form after database write

Comment: It's likely that something still needs teh form after OnActivate handler has executed. In this sort of scenario, I tend to set a flag, and then do teh close in FormShow, as that's the last handler in the sequence.